# Javascript выполнить действие до начала прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, javascript-events, mousewheel

У меня есть ПК с низкой производительностью. И сайт с разными эффектами. На нормальных ПК с нормальной производительностью все работает норм, а вот с низкой производительность - не очень. Я решил провести оптимизацию...

Например:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
        $('#el').css({color:'red'});
    });
```

Я прокручиваю страницу колесиком мыши. На ПК с низкой производительностью вижу:

1. Сначала происходит прокрутка контента.
2. И только потом применяется `$('#el').css({color:'red'});`

Пробовал плагин mousewheel https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

```
$(window).on('mousewheel',function() {
        $('#el').css({color:'red'});
    });
```

Эффект точно такойже. Сначала происходит прокрутка контента. И только потом применяется `$('#el').css({color:'red'});`

Вопрос как сделать чтоб сперва выполнялись все действия, такие как `$('#el').css({color:'red'});`
А уже потом происходила прокрутка страницы...
Что то вроде `$(window).on('beforeScroll',function(){});` ...
???

Comment: посмотрите [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164695/5398808), но есть минусы такого решения

Answer (score 0):

Ивент срабатывает только после прокрутки, так что сделать сначала красный цвет, а потом ппрокрутку с помощью этого ивента - не выйдет. При прокрутке вы можете делать красный цвет, использовать `window.scrollTo(X,Y);`, а затем уже `return false` чтобы функция не возвращала стандартную прокрутку.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
document.body.style.background = "red";
window.scrollTo({
    top: window.pageYOffset,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
 return false;
};
```

Comment: Неплохо бы не просто кинуть ссылку на теорию, но и сопроводить конкретным примером решения задачи. А пока формально - вы не ответили на вопрос, а лишь показали направление в котором вы думаете, что лежит решение. Подобные вещи обычно оставляют в комментариях, а не пишут в поле ответ.

Comment: Да-да. Вынужден проголосовать как не является ответом, чтобы модератор это перенёс в комментарии. Пожалуйста, используйте кнопку "ответ" для исчерпывающего ответа на вопрос, а не для намёков как решить задачу "дальше думайте сами".